# R httr GET request - connection time-out

Tags: r, get, ftp, httr

I am trying to download programmatically files like [this](ftp://fuoco.geog.umd.edu/gfed4/monthly/GFED4.0_MQ_200301_BA.hdf) from an ftp.
The home page provides openly username ("fire") and password ("burnt") and I can download the files no problem from browser.

When I try to do the same in R using httr::GET()

```
library("httr")
GET(url = "ftp://fuoco.geog.umd.edu/gfed4/monthly/GFED4.0_MQ_200301_BA.hdf",
    authenticate(user = "fire", password = "burnt"),
    write_disk(file.path(tempdir(), "GFED4.0_MQ_200301_BA.hdf"),
               overwrite = TRUE))
```

I get the following error

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) : 
  Timeout was reached: Connection time-out
```

I would greatly appreciate any idea to fix this problem, many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that FTP isn't supported by `library(httr)`:

Please see [this](https://github.com/r-lib/httr/issues/190#issuecomment-98742965), or more recent [this](https://github.com/r-lib/httr/issues/537#issuecomment-440760199).

I'd give `library(RCurl)` a go instead:

```
library(RCurl)
url <- "ftp://fuoco.geog.umd.edu/gfed4/monthly/GFED4.0_MQ_200301_BA.hdf"
content <- getBinaryURL(url, userpwd = "fire:burnt", ftp.use.epsv = FALSE)
writeBin(content, con = basename(url))
```